# Can't get data with Handlebars from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

Here is fiddle with code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/310z9gcj/)

```
{
  "status": {
    "success": true,
    "error": ""
  },
  "data": {
    "item": [
      {
        "name": "Test 1",
        "keywords": [
          "[asdad,dasdas]"
        ],
        "description": "xxzfrfa",
        "test": 12.3,
        "id": "584ab61344be2bd806ef276d"
      },
      {
        "name": "My test 2",
        "keywords": [
          "[zx,zz]"
        ],
        "description": "xz",
        "test": 53,
        "id": "584ab67b11b75c3a10fc1518"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

...

```
<div id="product-container"></div>
<script id="product-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each data.item}} 
        <h2>{{brand}}</h2>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

What can I do to return data from JSON ?..it's not working now.. If anyone can help me. I've tried a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is working, there is nothing to render since there is no `brand` field.

Here is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/panamaprophet/nbn39wzu/

(since i didnt found a `brand` field in your example, i replaced it with `name` just for demonstration).

Comment: thanks for answer..i've replaced with name..but won't work...nothing appears :(..no error in console.

Comment: make a `console.log` of your `productsData` parameter inside a function, does it's value looks correct?

Comment: and you can reach them via `data.item[0].name`?

Comment: Where I have to try this? On template or in console??

Comment: inside a function and inside a template

Comment: On template I've got an ugly long error ..and on console: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined. Little mention..my file extension is .hbs for handlebars, maybe it can help

Comment: oh, sure, it's a handlebars. sorry for last comment, try to doing this in a template `{{data.item.0.name}}`

Comment: Nothing happens:(

Comment: as i see, you need to include handlebars itself at first and only then include your own code script, which depends on a handlebars.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `name` of an `item` like below

```
{{#data.item}} 
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
{{/data.item}}
```

Sample code below: (Removed ajax to get it working here)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hh4vf4mk/)

Comment: Not working...maybe because it's hbs file extension?